# how to use one mysql query, update data without duplicate?

Tags: php, mysql

```
id | title | text
1  | aa    | 
2  | aa    |
3  | aa    |
```

I have some data from `json data`, i am not sure how many datas have duplicate in it.

```
$json = '[{"a":"1","b":"bb"},{"a":"2","b":"cc"},{"a":"3","b":"bb"}]';
$array = json_decode($json);
foreach($array as $key){
    UPDATE table SET text = '".$key->b."' WHERE id = '".$key->a."' and title='aa'");
}
```

For example, as this situation,  `$key->b` has 2 data `bb` from the json data, I only want update the first one and check if `bb` has already in the database, then ignore update.

```
id | title | text
1  | aa    | bb
2  | aa    | cc
3  | aa    |      <-ignore updtae, left the data empty
```

I know there have an easy way, first `select * from table where text != '$key->a'` for check, but this will cost 2 mysql query and make one more foreach, so

**how to use one mysql query, update data without duplicate?**

many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your database is MySQL, maybe you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @user1043095, this is insert? But I need update, the first 2 fields already in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an array to store all the values of `b` you have used so far and only run the `UPDATE` if the value didn't exist yet.

```
$json = '[{"a":"1","b":"bb"},{"a":"2","b":"cc"},{"a":"3","b":"bb"}]';
$usedValues = array();
$array = json_decode($json);
foreach($array as $key){
    if(!isset(usedValues[$key->b])) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET text = '".$key->b."' WHERE id = '".$key->a."' and title='aa'");
        usedValues[$key->b] = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If your database already has values for `text` this may still produce duplicates, but you could do a `SELECT DISTINCT ´text´` and populate the `$usedValues` array with them.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this would just scan the current `json data`, but if I have many `json data` will insert into database, how to avoid insert the duplicate data if I do mysql update from another `json data`?(1.txt,2.txt,3.txt... ) `json_decode(file_get_contents('1.txt'));`